# How to rename Ionic app from HelloCordova

Tags: ionic-framework

The Ionic framework is pretty great stuff.  I was able to successfully build an app with some Angular code I have been working on, but I can't find an answer to the simple question of how to rename the app that gets generated.  The output app is always called HelloCordova and there doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to change the name of the app.  If I start manually digging through the project directory replacing HelloCordova, I end up with an app that won't run.  Surely, people have solved this before.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

**Edit**: You want to change the `config.xml` file in your project's root directory.
The tag which is responsible for the app name is `<name>`.

look up the [config documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html) for more.

Comment: I'm going to give you credit because you led me to the right answer.  For whatever reason, Ionic has two copies of this same config.xml file, one in the root of your project and another in the www directory.  Changing this setting in the config.xml at the root of the project seems to set the name correctly.  Thanks!

Comment: I changed name tag in config.xml file  and after build but not change to my custom name, How solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for cordova version 4.

Comment: Esp. for Android, try [this](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/renaming-android-build-apk-from-cordovaapp-to-your-app-name/15416).

Comment: As of ionic v1.0, this should be renamed in the ionic.project file in order for the app name to be correct in ionic.io.

Comment: I changed the name in config.xml and ionic.project, but in order for Xcode to run it again I had to first run "ionic platform remove ios" and "ionic platform add ios".

Comment: FYI on version 4.10+ the commands are `ionic cordova platform remove ios` and `ionic cordova platform add ios`

Answer (score 31):

Updated

1. Change the name in **config.xml** (@ project root) see the : [documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/config_ref/index.html#link-1).
2. Execute this command : **$ sudo ionic cordova platform remove ios**
3. Check if the folder **ios** under **platforms** folder is deleted.
4. Execute this command : **$ sudo ionic cordova platform add ios**

Comment: This worked for me but a warning: don't use sudo if you don't have to. Using sudo messed up the permissions in the cordova config files for my user account. I used sudo and then had to reset the permissions after additional cli commands triggered permission errors.

Comment: @mrjrdnthms how did you reset permissions - this just broke my environment and initial searches online have not helped. Looking for a quick answer as I'm in a hackathon!

Comment: I ended up fixing this issue by resetting the permissions on the Cordova `packages` folder. eg: `sudo chown -R $USER /Users/<username>/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-ios/<version>/package/`

Comment: The platform command has been renamed.
`ionic cordova platform remove ios`

Comment: why do we need sudo?

Comment: It's better to be sure all the platform files are deleted correctly and to start adda new platform from scratch

Answer (score 6):

If changing the `name` is not working for any reason delete entire platform folder and then

```
cordova platform add ios
ionic build ios
```

Answer (score 5):

If your looking to change the iconic view name be sure to also update ionic.project

Comment: run "ionic upload"

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you just have to modify the config.xml. Find a "name" tag and put your required name between this tag.

Answer (score 3):

The following steps will help you as it did to me.

1. Rename app name in config.xml 
   `<name>Your_new_name</name>`
2. ionic cordova plugin save
3. ionic cordova rm ios
4. ionic cordova add ios
5. ionic cordova plugin add --save cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="my_app_id" --variable APP_NAME="my_app_name" --variable CHANNEL_NAME="master"

Answer (score 2):

In the parent directory of the ionic project there is a config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.todo497320" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>CHANGE NAME HERE</name>
```

Note that the project name will be seen in various other places in the app, all these will be changed automatically when the app is built

Answer (score 1):

In the parent directory of the ionic project there is a config.xml

CHANGE NAME HERE

If changing the name is not working for any reason delete entire platform folder and then

cordova platform add ios
ionic build ios

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I'm getting this error when try to compile back after rename; `error invalid data chunk must be a string or buffer not object cordova`. I did `cordova platform rm android` but still getting the error. I get it working after delete the `platform` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You should make this change in the config.xml found at the root of your project. For example you might have something like this:

`***<widget id="com.ionicframework.exampleproject223738" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">***`

Change the id to whatever you wish your package to be and it will work for the entire project, Android and iOS.

However, if you've already submitted to the app store with a package name, you cannot change the package name at this point. Not unless you want to submit a new project. Updates must be made with matching package names.

Answer (score 0):

For ionic 4.5.0 the "ionic platform" command  has been renamed and the following commands are not used anymore:

- ionic platform remove ios
- ionic platform add ios

Instead use:

- ionic cordova platform add ios
- ionic cordova platform remove ios

Note: ios or android depending on your case